# How do you get help with operators?

Tags: help-system

How can I get help on operators as opposed to normal mode commands? For example, if I type the following:

```
:h .
```

Then I will get the help on the normal mode dot command, not on the string concatenation operator which is the same symbol.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know about string concatenation, you can use the help entry `:h expr-.`

Note, the help tags follow a generic style, which if you know it, it helps to find the correct tag. (e.g. options are always enclosed in single quotes). To learn about that, check the help (of course :)) at [`:h help-summary`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_02.txt.html#help-summary)

Answer (score 2):

The help tags for those are usually prefixed with `expr-`. For example: [`:help expr-.`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-.):

```
expr5 and expr6                                         expr5 expr6
---------------
expr6 +  expr6 ..       Number addition or List concatenation expr-+
expr6 -  expr6 ..       Number subtraction                      expr--
expr6 .  expr6 ..       String concatenation                    expr-.

For Lists only "+" is possible and then both expr6 must be a list.  The
result is a new list with the two lists Concatenated.

expr7 *  expr7 ..       Number multiplication                   expr-star
expr7 /  expr7 ..       Number division                         expr-/
expr7 %  expr7 ..       Number modulo                           expr-%
```